# How often does coreLocation Update

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using the CoreLocation Framework and im curious how often it updates, its really inaccurate and im debating on calling the method from an NSTimer to increase how often its used. My code is Below

in ViewDidLoad

```
//location update
CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
CLController.delegate = self;
[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

my void methods

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {

    int speedInt = [location speed]*2.23693629;
    if(speedInt < 0){
        speedInt = 0;
    }
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", speedInt];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    speedLabel.text = [error description];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The frequency of updates is determined by a combination of [`desiredAccuracy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18) and [`distanceFilter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/distanceFilter) (and, obviously, how much the user is moving). A `distanceFilter` of `kCLDistanceFilterNone` and `desiredAccuracy` of [`kCLLocationAccuracyBest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBest) or `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` will get you the most updates (but drain your battery the fastest).

Using a `NSTimer` will not achieve greater accuracy. Rely upon `CLLocationManager` to update with the desired frequency, with some sensitivity to a reasonable balance between the app's requirements and the user's desire to not drain his or her battery unnecessarily.

See the [Starting the Standard Location Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW7) section of the *Location Awareness Programming Guide.* Also see the [Tips for Conserving Battery Power](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW17) section in that guide.

Comment: Small addition: "best for navigation" currently updates once per second. This isn't often enough for my navigation app - I plan to try using the accelerometer to guestimate the location in between core location updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign desiredAccuracy property of CLLocationManager to kCLLocationAccuracyBest:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate= self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow your code sense, that you can add this :

```
CLController.locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
CLController.locMgr.distanceFilter  = 10.0f; //To set updating distance up with x meter when you leaved the scope.
[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

Hope it can help you.